# How do you get WHERE to work in a C# program?

Tags: c#, sql, database

I'm having a problem with figuring out why my `WHERE` won't give me everything. I'm currently trying to make a database interface program for my company so we can move off the one we have. Now I'll admit it's been a while since I've done any work with databases so I'm a tad rusty. Anyway, I've got a part of my program that will be for searching the database and as such it does regular searching just fine, but when I try to get it to do `WHERE` it only gives me one name if anything. I've been fiddling around with the code, trying with adding parts like another `dataReader.GetName()` and `dataReader.GetValue()` to the output but it just fusses at me and doesn't like it.

I'm not sure if it's a problem with where it is in the code or I'm not asking it to do the right thing. All I know is it's very likely some real small thing I'm missing. This is the code that I have that I thought should be giving me all the names of everything that the `WHERE` pulls up:

```
while (dataReader.Read())
{
    Output = Output + dataReader.GetName(0) + ": " + 
    dataReader.GetValue(0);
    Output = Output + "\n";
}
```

However, it only gives me one and it's the one from the very end of the list to boot. I've tried to increment the number in the dataReaders using a variable but it gives me index out of bounds when I do. Is it possible it's starting the reading at the end? Here's the full code, apologies for the length, dealing with the output:

```
    public static string LowerFirst(string value)
    { 
        // This is so strings can be converted to camelCase format if they need to be.
        if (value.Length > 0)
        {
            var letters = value.ToCharArray();
            letters[0] = char.ToLowerInvariant(letters[0]);
            return new string(letters);
        }
        return value;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection cnn;
        cnn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=M;Integrated Security=SSPI");
        cnn.Open();

        SqlCommand command;
        SqlDataReader dataReader;
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        string sql = "Select ";
        string Output = "";
        string b1 = LowerFirst(columnBox1.Text.Replace(" ", ""));
        string b2 = LowerFirst(columnBox2.Text.Replace(" ", ""));
        string b3 = LowerFirst(columnBox3.Text.Replace(" ", ""));
        string b4 = LowerFirst(columnBox4.Text.Replace(" ", ""));
        string b5 = LowerFirst(columnBox5.Text.Replace(" ", ""));
        string tabl = tableGroupbox.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().FirstOrDefault(r => r.Checked).Text;
        string wer1 = LowerFirst(columnChoice2.SelectedItem.ToString().Replace(" ", ""));
        string wer2 = conditionTxtbox.Text;
        string wer3 = LowerFirst(columnChoice1.SelectedItem.ToString().Replace(" ", ""));
        int c = 0;
        int l = 5;
        int serNum = 0;
        int chCount = 0;


        if (everythingBox.Checked == true)
        {
          // Resets the check boxes in case.
            if (columnBox1.Checked == true) columnBox1.Checked = false; 
            if (columnBox2.Checked == true) columnBox2.Checked = false;
            if (columnBox3.Checked == true) columnBox3.Checked = false;
            if (columnBox4.Checked == true) columnBox4.Checked = false;
            if (columnBox5.Checked == true) columnBox5.Checked = false;
            sql = sql + "*"; 
        }
        else if (tableName1Radiobutton.Checked == true) sql = sql + "invoiceID"; else if (tableName2Radiobutton.Checked == true) sql = sql + "customerID"; else if (tableName3Radiobutton.Checked == true) sql = sql + "itemID";
       
        //Sets up order and what is counted in regards to spaces.
        if (columnBox1.Checked == true) sql = sql + "," + b1; chCount = chCount + 1;
        if (columnBox2.Checked == true && chCount != 0)
        {
            sql = sql + "," + b2;
            chCount++;
        }          
        else if (columnBox2.Checked == true && chCount == 0)
        {
            sql += b2;
            chCount++;
        }

        if (columnBox3.Checked == true && chCount != 0)
        {
            sql = sql + "," + b3;
            chCount++;
        }
        else if (columnBox3.Checked == true && chCount == 0)
        {
            sql = sql + b3;
            chCount++;
        }
        if (columnBox4.Checked == true && chCount != 0)
        {
            sql = sql + "," + b4;
            chCount++;
        }
        else if (columnBox4.Checked == true && chCount == 0)
        {
            sql = sql + b4;
            chCount++;
        }
        if (columnBox5.Checked == true && chCount != 0) sql = sql + "," + b5; else if (columnBox5.Checked == true) sql = sql + b5;

        MessageBox.Show(chCount.ToString());

        sql = sql + " from " + tabl;

        if (whereChkbox.Checked == true)
        {
            // Set up to perform a targeted search. However.... 
            MessageBox.Show(wer1);
            sql = "SELECT * FROM " + tabl + " WHERE " + wer1 + "='" + wer2 + "'"; 

        }

        // Used to tell what boxes have been checked. Now rendered moot by other code?
        if (columnBox1.Checked == true) serNum = serNum + 1;
        if (columnBox2.Checked == true) serNum = serNum + 2;
        if (columnBox3.Checked == true) serNum = serNum + 4;
        if (columnBox4.Checked == true) serNum = serNum + 8;
        if (columnBox5.Checked == true) serNum = serNum + 16;
        if (everythingBox.Checked == true) serNum = 0;
       
        // The l would tell the output how far to go with the help of a c int. 
        if (serNum == 1 || serNum == 2 || serNum == 4 || serNum == 8 || serNum == 16) l = 2;
        if (serNum == 3 || serNum == 5 || serNum == 9 || serNum == 17 || serNum == 6 || serNum == 10 || serNum == 18 || serNum == 12 || serNum == 20 || serNum == 24) l = 3;
        if (serNum == 7 || serNum == 11 || serNum == 19 || serNum == 13 || serNum == 21 || serNum == 25 || serNum == 14 || serNum == 22 || serNum == 28 || serNum == 26) l = 4;
        if (serNum == 0 || serNum == 15 || serNum == 23 || serNum == 29 || serNum == 27 || serNum == 30) l = 5;
        if (serNum == 31) l = 6;
        if (serNum == 0 && columnBox5.Checked == true) l = 6;
        MessageBox.Show(sql,serNum.ToString());

        command = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn);
        dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

        // Controls how far the dataReader reads to prevent out of bounds on the index. 
        while (dataReader.Read() && whereChkbox.Checked == false)
        {
            Output = Output + " " + dataReader.GetName(0) + ": " + dataReader.GetValue(0);
            
            if (everythingBox.Checked == true)
            {
                if (tableName3Radiobutton.Checked == true) Output = Output + " " + dataReader.GetName(1) + ": " + dataReader.GetValue(1) + " " + dataReader.GetName(2) + ": " + dataReader.GetValue(2) + " " + dataReader.GetName(3) + ": " + dataReader.GetValue(3) + " " + dataReader.GetName(4) + ": " + dataReader.GetValue(4) + " " + dataReader.GetName(5) + ": " + dataReader.GetValue(5);
                else Output = Output + " " + dataReader.GetName(1) + ": " + dataReader.GetValue(1) + " " + dataReader.GetName(2) + ": " + dataReader.GetValue(2) + " " + dataReader.GetName(3) + ": " + dataReader.GetValue(3) + " " + dataReader.GetName(4) + ": " + dataReader.GetValue(4);
            }
            else if (columnBox5.Checked == true)
            {
                if (columnBox1.Checked == true && columnBox2.Checked == true && columnBox3.Checked == true && columnBox4.Checked == true) Output = Output + " " + dataReader.GetName(1) + ": " + dataReader.GetValue(1) + " " + dataReader.GetName(2) + ": " + dataReader.GetValue(2) + " " + dataReader.GetName(3) + ": " + dataReader.GetValue(3) + " " + dataReader.GetName(4) + ": " + dataReader.GetValue(4) + " " + dataReader.GetName(5) + ": " + dataReader.GetValue(5); 
                else if(columnBox1.Checked == true && columnBox2.Checked == true && columnBox3.Checked == true || columnBox1.Checked == true && columnBox3.Checked == true && columnBox4.Checked == true || columnBox1.Checked == true && columnBox2.Checked == true && columnBox4.Checked == true || columnBox2.Checked == true && columnBox3.Checked == true && columnBox4.Checked == true) Output = Output + " " + dataReader.GetName(1) + ": " + dataReader.GetValue(1) + " " + dataReader.GetName(2) + ": " + dataReader.GetValue(2) + " " + dataReader.GetName(3) + ": " + dataReader.GetValue(3) + " " + dataReader.GetName(4) + ": " + dataReader.GetValue(4);
                else if (columnBox1.Checked == true && columnBox2.Checked == true || columnBox1.Checked == true && columnBox3.Checked == true || columnBox1.Checked == true && columnBox4.Checked == true || columnBox2.Checked == true && columnBox3.Checked == true || columnBox2.Checked == true && columnBox4.Checked == true || columnBox3.Checked == true && columnBox4.Checked == true) Output = Output + " " + dataReader.GetName(1) + ": " + dataReader.GetValue(1) + " " + dataReader.GetName(2) + ": " + dataReader.GetValue(2) + " " + dataReader.GetName(3) + ": " + dataReader.GetValue(3);
                else if (columnBox1.Checked == true || columnBox2.Checked == true || columnBox3.Checked == true || columnBox4.Checked == true) Output = Output + " " + dataReader.GetName(1) + ": " + dataReader.GetValue(1) + " " + dataReader.GetName(2) + ": " + dataReader.GetValue(2);
                else Output = Output + " " + dataReader.GetName(1) + ": " + dataReader.GetValue(1);
            }
            else if (columnBox4.Checked == true)
            {
                if (columnBox1.Checked == true && columnBox2.Checked == true && columnBox3.Checked == true || columnBox1.Checked == true && columnBox3.Checked == true && columnBox5.Checked == true || columnBox2.Checked == true && columnBox3.Checked == true && columnBox5.Checked == true) Output = Output + " " + dataReader.GetName(1) + ": " + dataReader.GetValue(1) + " " + dataReader.GetName(2) + ": " + dataReader.GetValue(2) + " " + dataReader.GetName(3) + ": " + dataReader.GetValue(3) + " " + dataReader.GetName(4) + ": " + dataReader.GetValue(4);
                else if (columnBox1.Checked == true && columnBox2.Checked == true || columnBox1.Checked == true && columnBox3.Checked == true || columnBox1.Checked == true && columnBox5.Checked == true || columnBox2.Checked == true && columnBox3.Checked == true || columnBox2.Checked == true && columnBox5.Checked == true || columnBox3.Checked == true && columnBox5.Checked == true) Output = Output + " " + dataReader.GetName(1) + ": " + dataReader.GetValue(1) + " " + dataReader.GetName(2) + ": " + dataReader.GetValue(2) + " " + dataReader.GetName(3) + ": " + dataReader.GetValue(3);
                else if (columnBox1.Checked == true || columnBox2.Checked == true || columnBox3.Checked == true || columnBox5.Checked == true) Output = Output + " " + dataReader.GetName(1) + ": " + dataReader.GetValue(1) + " " + dataReader.GetName(2) + ": " + dataReader.GetValue(2);
                else Output = Output + " " + dataReader.GetName(1) + ": " + dataReader.GetValue(1);
            }
            else if (columnBox3.Checked == true)
            {
              if (columnBox1.Checked == true && columnBox2.Checked == true) Output = Output + " " + dataReader.GetName(1) + ": " + dataReader.GetValue(1) + " " + dataReader.GetName(2) + ": " + dataReader.GetValue(2) + " " + dataReader.GetName(3) + ": " + dataReader.GetValue(3); 
              else if (columnBox1.Checked == true || columnBox2.Checked == true) Output = Output + " " + dataReader.GetName(1) + ": " + dataReader.GetValue(1) + " " + dataReader.GetName(2) + ": " + dataReader.GetValue(2); 
              else Output = Output + " " + dataReader.GetName(1) + ": " + dataReader.GetValue(1);
            }
            else if (columnBox2.Checked == true)
            {
                if (columnBox1.Checked == true) Output = Output + " " + dataReader.GetName(1) + ": " + dataReader.GetValue(1) + " " + dataReader.GetName(2) + ": " + dataReader.GetValue(2); else Output = Output + " " + dataReader.GetName(1) + ": " + dataReader.GetValue(1);
            }
            else if (columnBox1.Checked == true) Output = Output + " " + dataReader.GetName(1) + ": " + dataReader.GetValue(1);
            Output = Output + "\n"; 
            
        }

        //Should give you the results of a targeted search. However it's currently not wanting to do so. 
        if (whereChkbox.Checked == true)
        {
            while (dataReader.Read())
           {
            Output = Output + dataReader.GetName(0) + ": " + dataReader.GetValue(0);
            Output = Output + "\n";

           }

        } 
        dataReader.Close();
        command.Dispose();

        richTextBox1.Text = Output;
        if (seprateWindbox.Checked == true) MessageBox.Show(Output);
        cnn.Close();
    }
```

If you need me to provide more/better information just let me know and thanks in advance for any help. And here is a picture of the program with the message box showing the sql that is going into it, so it in case that helps. [image: Picture of the program.]

Comment: Umm, my glasorb complains about the limited information here. Too little code. Maybe you are missing some piece of code that reads almost all the results or the WHERE clause is off. Maybe try the executing the SQL 1:1 in some frontend.

Comment: Please include your actual SQL statement. What Database System are you using? What happens if you execute the statement directly on the database?

Comment: Think you should start with an ORM and work backwards if you need to

Comment: You still don't have the most important part, where you populate the datareader and how the SQL statment is constructed. Please use more meaninful field names than "checkbox8" how are we, or any future developers on your project, meant to know what they represent. Keep in mind datareaders are only meant to be read once.

Comment: @JonP I added in the rest of the code and changed the names to hopefully better reflect what is going on. Let me know if I need to do anything else to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reconsider your `while` loops. `dataReader.Read()` is being called twice for your by the time you get to your targeted search.

I'd go with something like the following:

```
while (dataReader.Read())
{
   if (whereChkbox.Checked)
   {
      Output = Output + dataRead
   }
   else
   {
      //Alternate logic here
   }
}
```

Alternatively reorder the first `while` statement to

```
while (whereChkbox.Checked == false && dataReader.Read())
{
    //logic here
}
```

That way if the checkbox is checked, the following `data.Read()` will not occur do to logic [short circuiting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators)

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you!